# Global Search for variables in MS ACCESS databases

Tags: database, ms-access

I inherited a Microsoft Access database.
Actually I'm new to Access.

Some variable names (e.g. name of a table, name of a column or name of a file) appear very often distributed over queries, forms and tables. And they have to be adapted in all those site when you apply changes to the design of the database. 
Does the MS Access API provide any way to **globally search for the occurrence of these variables**.
How not to get lost? :=)

Comment: The autocorrect feature is supposed to update all occurrences of the Column name or whatever as its changed. This doesn't work that well though see http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html

Comment: You forgot to delete your off-topic question over here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/323455

Comment: Hello Robert, thanks for the hint - meanwhile I found the botton to delete:=)
Thank you for your patience with the unexperienced user.

Answer (score 1):

Use Rick Fisher's Find and Replace. http://www.rickworld.com/index.html